# Is there a way to customize breadcrumbs in Emacs Orgmode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I set `org-agenda-prefix-format` with `%b`, I got all higher levels headline shown in the agenda .Is there any way to show only parent level, without other higher levels shown.

I have tried:

```
'((todo . " %-25(concat \"[\"(truncate-string-to-width (car (last
(org-get-outline-path))) 21 nil nil t) \"]\")"))
```

It works ok with `todo`.
However, when I tried on `agenda`:

```
'((agenda . " %-25(concat \"[\"(truncate-string-to-width (car (last
(org-get-outline-path))) 21 nil nil t) \"]\")"))
```

my custom command:

```
("n" "Agenda and all TODOs"
      ((agenda "" nil)
       (alltodo "" nil))
      nil)
```

did not work, only agenda but no todo shown.

update:
If there is no agenda items for today, the agenda view shows ok with both todo and agenda. However, If there is an agenda items for today, the todo won't show any more. Does my `org-agenda-prefix-format` config affect the timeline or something? This really makes me confused.